# Conversion from string to float of numerical values (scientific notation)

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I am using Python for reading a file and converting numerical value written as string to float. I observe a weird conversion:

```
 a="-5.970471694E+02"

 b = float(a)
 b
 >> -597.0471694

 bb = np.float64(a)
 bb
 >> -597.04716940000003

 e="-5.970471695E+02"
 ee = np.float64(e)
 ee
 >> -597.0471695

 ee-bb
 >> -9.9999965641472954e-08
```

What is the reason of the term "0000003" at the end of `bb`. Why I don't observe the same thing for `ee`. Is this really a problem? I think this issue is due to the floating-point accuracy but the result seems to be perturbed before I start to use the variables...

Comment: something seems wrong with your example   >>> a="-5.970471694E+09"
>>> b = float(a)
>>> b
-5970471694.0
>>>    is what I get... addendum, I am using python 3.4.1 what version are you using?

Comment: In your example, `b` should be `-5970471694.0`, not `-597.04716940000003`.

Comment: @DanPatterson yes yes.... I correct it !! Sorry

Comment: in python 3.4.1 and numpy version 1.9.0 ... >>> a="-5.970471694E+02"
>>> bb = np.float(a)
>>> bb
-597.0471694
>>>   but I still get  bb-ee = 9.9999965641472954e-08 which is floating point representation

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215437/floating-point-accuracy-in-python? Also read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the reason of the term "0000003" at the end of `bb`. Why I don't observe the same thing for `ee`.

`b` and `bb` have identical values (try evaluating `b == bb`). The difference comes down to how they are represented by the interpreter. By default, numpy floats are displayed with 8 digits after the decimal place, whereas Python floats are printed to 13 significant digits (including those before the decimal place).

> Is this really a problem?

Since the actual values of `b` and `bb` are identical then the answer is almost certainly no. If the display differences bother you, you can use [`np.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) to control how numpy floats are represented in the interpreter. If you use IPython, you can also use the [`%precision` magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.basic.html#IPython.core.magics.basic.BasicMagics.precision) to control how regular Python floats are printed.

Comment: Ok thank you! As I expected this "issue" (not a real one) is the same as we observe with many scientific softwares and that can lead to some round-off errors.

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of mistaking the number of *displayed* digits for the precision of the underlying float value. On a 64 bit machine, `float` and `np.float64` will both be 64 bit. Regardless of whether you display them with 1 or 100 decimal places they will still have exactly the same underlying precision, and will show the same degree of rounding error when you use them in calculations.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. The use of the `decimal`module can help to see the decimals

Answer (score -1):

Both float and float64 use a binary representation of the number. Both have to save the approximation that is caused by conversion from the number with base 10 to the number with base 2. The float uses less bits, so the error is greater and it is made visible when the `a` is copied to `b`. That is because `b` takes the `a` including the rounding error without the loss of information, and the `a` contains that `000..03` value. In other words, it is a rounding error from converting a decimal number to a binary number.